# What's the most efficient way to query Microsoft Graph events by id list?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Currently, in my code, I am taking a list of stored `Event` ids and fetching them like this:

```cs
results = await Task.WhenAll(
    criteria.Identifiers
        .Skip(offset).Take(pageSize)
        .Select(i => userEvents[i].Request(options).GetAsync())
        .ToList());
```

This works fine, but it makes `pageSize` number of calls to the API, which seems less than ideal. Is there a way to bundle these identifiers into a single API call?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/directoryobject_getbyids

Comment: @cptwonton Something like that, yes. However, this specifically relates to Events and to the Microsoft.Graph NuGet library, since I don't want to break form and make raw JSON API calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question proved similar to another:

[Getting multiple users/groups by objectids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236017/getting-multiple-users-groups-by-objectids)

The answer, there, suggests this feature might be coming, but isn't here, yet. If anyone knows more about the timeline, please add another answer or comment.